# /etc/hosts get all domains?

Tags: networking

I want to prank my brother by throwing all domains he tries to visit to a webserver I have on the network.
but how do I edit his `/etc/hosts` file in such a way that I will redirect everything to that server?
`192.168.48.2` is the server

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You could do this with squid or iptables, though!

Many years ago, I pranked a friend much more easily by adding to his autoexec.bat:

echo "Yes means no and no means yes.  Delete all files?"
pause

That was much simpler and just as funny ;-)

Comment: my brother is not 'dumb' enough to fall for that :p however, he doesn't know about `/etc/host` so that has more impact.

but I guess I'll just use a little bash script for it then (I know all the sites he visits often so)